# Why is PHP putting a random number in the middle of my HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage structured like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php echo readfile("https://example.com/example/".urldecode($_GET["path"])."/head.html");?>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="/"><img src="../../../../../img/header.png" alt="Some alt text..." height="94" width="334"></a>
        <p><a href="/contents/">Contents</a> | <a href="/about/">About</a> | <a href="/contact/">Contact</a></p>
    </header>
    <p>Some text...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've got a head, a header, and a body of text beneath the header. My goal is to use some PHP code to load some of the head information (such as the meta tags, the document title, and the CSS files) dynamically, but this code is doing something really weird — whenever it runs, it inserts a random string — "876" — between `<body>` and `<header>`. This string renders to the user as plain text, making the whole page look wrong.

Is there anything wrong with my code that could be making this happen? As far as I can tell, the PHP code shouldn't even have access to the body of the document, but this random string only appears when the PHP code is in the `<head>` section.

(I suppose it's worth noting that the PHP code *does* work — it loads the head data just fine, and everything renders perfectly... except for that stupid "876" in the top left corner.

Comment: The only content it inserts is `876` and it's always `876`? This happens in any browser?

Comment: @j08691 Yep — so far, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `readfile()` function outputs the contents of the file and returns the number of bytes. So `echo readfile("...")` outputs the contents of the URL, then it echoes the number of bytes. `876` is the size of the contents of the URL.

You don't need `echo` when you're using `readfile()`, since it does its own printing. Your code would be correct if you were using `file_get_contents()`.